# join three tables for specific result

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have three tables:

**Table 1** `Users`:

```
+----------+------------+------------+-------------------+
| ID [PK]  |  username  |  password  |  user_struct [FK] |
+----------+------------+------------+-------------------+
|       1  |  SAM       |       123  |  CIF              |
|       2  |  JACK      |       123  |  ADM              |
|       3  |  JAMAL     |       123  |  SDT              |
+----------+------------+------------+-------------------+
```

**Table 2** `CR_AR`:

```
+-------------+-------+--------------+
| ID_CR [PK]  |  NUM  |  STRUCT [FK] |
+-------------+-------+--------------+
|          1  |   11  |  CIF         |
|          2  |   22  |  ADM         |
|          3  |   33  |  SDT         |
+-------------+-------+--------------+
```

**Table 3** `STRUCT`:

```
+-----------------+--------------+
| STRUCTURE [PK]  |  description |
+-----------------+--------------+
| CIF             |  NULL        |
| IDM             |  NULL        |
| SDT             |  NULL        |
+-----------------+--------------+
```

I need to join the three tables so I can get data from `CR_AR` table only when `STRUCT` value is the same in all three tables.

This is the SQL query I wrote but it seems to return all data even if `user_struct` in `USERS` is not equal to `STRUCT` in `CR_AR`

```sql
SELECT * FROM CR_AR AS C 
    LEFT JOIN STRUCT AS S ON S.STRUCTURE = C.STRUCT 
    LEFT JOIN USERS AS U ON U.USER_STRUCT = S.STRUCTURE
```

Comment: change all the "Left join" to "Join"

Comment: Why are you using left join? Have you looked at the result after the first left join? (Absolutely basic debugging.) Do you understand that left join returns inner join rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `LEFT JOIN` will always return **all** records from the table on the **left** of the join, and only values from those records which match the join criteria from tables on the **right** of the join.

To only return records for which there join criteria is validated for **every** record, you should use an `INNER JOIN`, i.e.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    CR_AR C 
    INNER JOIN STRUCT S ON S.STRUCTURE = C.STRUCT 
    INNER JOIN USERS U ON U.USER_STRUCT = S.STRUCTURE
```

Comment: right! but the query still return all data even if STRUCT from CR_AR is not equal to STRUCT in USER

Comment: example for **SAM** i want it to return only 

 1  |   11 

not the whole data of CR_AR

Comment: @YOUCEFsami Please provide full sample data and show the result you obtain when running the query.

Comment: @YOUCEFsami Lee's query will only return the 1/11 rows from CR_AR for Users.username='SAM'. Did you try running it before you raised your concern?

Answer (score 0):

Your data example talks about foreign keys, but table STRUCT does not contain ADM, but IDM. So something is inconsistent there.

If you do not want all the rows to be returned, you should not use outer joins. Use inner joins instead.

Here is my test, based on your example, with a couple of suggested queries you might find useful:

```
create table users (
    id int,
    username varchar(10),
    pwd varchar(10),
    user_struct varchar(3)
)

create table cr_ar (
    id int,
    num int,
    struct varchar(3)
)

create table struct (
    structure varchar(3),
    description varchar(10)
)

insert into users values (1, 'sam', 123, 'CIF')
insert into users values (2, 'jack', 123, 'ADM')
insert into users values (3, 'jamal', 123, 'SDT')

insert into cr_ar values (1, 11, 'CIF')
insert into cr_ar values (2, 22, 'ADM')
insert into cr_ar values (3, 33, 'SDT')

insert into struct values ('CIF', null)
insert into struct values ('IDM', null)
insert into struct values ('SDT', null)

-- your query
SELECT * FROM CR_AR AS C 
LEFT JOIN STRUCT AS S ON S.STRUCTURE = C.STRUCT 
LEFT JOIN USERS AS U ON U.USER_STRUCT = S.STRUCTURE

-- no outer joins
SELECT * FROM CR_AR AS C 
JOIN STRUCT AS S ON S.STRUCTURE = C.STRUCT 
JOIN USERS AS U ON U.USER_STRUCT = S.STRUCTURE

-- alternative with outer joins (showing struct ADM does not exist)
SELECT * FROM CR_AR AS C 
LEFT JOIN USERS AS U ON U.USER_STRUCT = C.struct
LEFT JOIN struct AS s ON s.structure = c.struct
```

Comment: sorry, it's ADM it was a writing mistake, the table STRUCT contain ADM

Comment: Then I do not understand when you say "user_struct in USERS is not equal to STRUCT in CR_AR". In your example, both tables contain the same set of values in their "structure" columns.